# Форма обратной связи, отправка почты springboot

Tags: java, bootstrap, spring-boot, rest, sendmail

Делаю обратную связь в вэб приложении

Написал модальное окно:

```
 <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title">Форма обратной связи</h5>
                                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"></button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">

                                <form>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div align="left">  <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Ваш моб. телефон</label></div>
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="+791223456789">
                                        <div align="left"> <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Cообщение</label></div>
                                        <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
                                       <div align="right"> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button></div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Так же RestCOntrolle

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/email")
public class EmailRestController {

private final EmailService emailService;


@Autowired
public EmailRestController(EmailService emailService) {
    this.emailService = emailService;
}

@GetMapping(value = "/{shop-email}/{communication}/{message}")
public @ResponseBody
ResponseEntity sendSimpleEmail(@PathVariable("shop-email") String email, @PathVariable("communication") String communication, @PathVariable("message") String message) {

    try {
        emailService.sendSimpleEmail(email, communication, message);
    } catch (MailException mailException) {

        return new ResponseEntity<>("Unable to send email", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

    return ResponseEntity.ok("Обращение отправлено");
}
```

Как мне передать данные из полей формы в контроллер, а конкретно чтобы из поля моб телефона данные пришли в переменную communication, а из текстового поля в переменную message

Comment: Не шарю в jave , но думаю очевидно что тут нужен метод get или post, в сетевом пакете джавы по-любому же есть методы для извлечения от туда инфы, в этом направление и гуглите

Answer (score 0):

Это зависит от модели. Если это RestContoller, то нужно использовать JavaScript для выполнения отправки данных по формату протокола обмена. В противном случае нужно использовать классический MVC: посмотрите на то, как использовать шаблонизатор Thymeleaf, например.